# Inconveniente anidando array en php para generar archivo JSON

Tags: php, array, json, jsonarray

Hola estoy haciendo un envío de datos desde woocommerce a un servicio externo de facturación para registrar los datos de la compra en un objeto json, sin embargo cuando envío los datos solamente llegan los datos recolectados en el array de Productos, los otros datos no llegan, este es el fragmento del codigo para crear el objeto JSON

```
  $data = array(
            "Ambiente" => "test",
            "NitEmisor" => "1234567",
            "FechaEmision" => date('Y-m-d'),
            "HoraEmision" => date('H:i:s'),
            "CustomerName" => $customer_name,
            "CustomerCity" => "Ciudad",
            "CustomerDepto" => "Departamento",
            "CustomerAddress" => $order->get_billing_address_1() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_address_2(),
            "CustomerNit" => "12334567",
            "CustomerEmail" => $customer_email,
            "CustomerIdCode" => "13",
            "CustomerPhone" => $customer_phone,
            "Subtotal" => $subtotal_total,
            "IvaTotal" => $iva_total,
            "TotalFactura" => $subtotal_total + $iva_total,
        );
        
        // Obtiene los productos del pedido de WooCommerce
        $line_items = $order->get_items();
         $products = array();
        // Agrega los productos al array de productos en el objeto JSON
        foreach ($line_items as $item) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $subtotal = $product->get_price() * $item->get_quantity();
            $iva = $subtotal * 0.19;
            $total = $subtotal + $iva;
        
            $producto = array(
                "Cantidad" => $item->get_quantity(),
                "SutotalProducto" => $subtotal,
                "TotalIvaProducto" => $iva,
                "TotalProducto" => $total,
                "PorcentageIVA" => 19,
                "NombreProducto" => $product->get_name(),
            );
            
            array_push($products, $producto);
        // Agrega el producto al array de productos en el objeto JSON
        }
        
        $data["Productos"] = $products;
        // Convertir el array $data a JSON
        $json_data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Lo que esta llegando es lo siguiente `{"{"Productos":":{"{"Cantidad":1,"SutotalProducto":195000,"TotalIvaProducto":37050,"TotalProducto":232050,"PorcentageIVA":19,"NombreProducto":"FLOWER BOX NEGRO"}":null}}`

Y esto es lo que deberia quedar en el objeto JSON, cuando ya recopile los datos completos del pedido de woocommerce

Ejemplo JSON

```
{
   "Ambiente":"test",
   "NitEmisor":"123446",
   "FechaEmision":"2023-08-01",
   "HoraEmision":"21:26:39",
   "CustomerName":"NombreComprador",
   "CustomerCity":"Ciudad",
   "CustomerDepto":"Departamento",
   "CustomerAddress":"Dirección",
   "CustomerNit":"1032413224",
   "CustomerEmail":"correocomprador",
   "CustomerIdCode":"13",
   "CustomerPhone":"3194578991",
   "ValorBaseGravada":555000,
   "Subtotal":885000,
   "IvaTotal":105450,
   "TotalFactura":990450,
   "Productos":[
      {
         "Cantidad":1,
         "SutotalProducto":125000,
         "TotalIvaProducto":23750,
         "TotalProducto":148750,
         "PorcentageIVA":19,
         "NombreProducto":"Chivas extra 700ml"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: puedes incluir cual es la salida actual de tu array y cual es la que esperas, en texto?

Comment: Ya edité la publicación para mostrar la salida actual y lo que solo esta quedando en el json, y cual es la esperada.

Comment: me parece que no concuerda lo que dices que suecede con tu script, aqui te dejo un breve ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo y de como comprobar que el json se esta armando: https://onlinephp.io/c/97670

Comment: esta linea: $data["Productos"] = $products; no debera reiniciar la variable a menos que tenga algun error en los parentecis etc ...

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón con $data["Productos"] = $products;, lo revisé en el sandbox y me genera el json como lo necesito, voy a eliminar el plugin del wordpress, limpiar cache y realizar pruebas nuevamente, a ver que salida me genera